# Can I use a variable as a property name in a Firebase Firestore .update() method? (Google Firebase & JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a variable with a string and a firebase update method:

```
let name = 'NAME';

firebase.firestore.collection('test').doc('main').update({
  name: 'text'
})
```

So can I use the variable in the property section?
If not, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the variable name in square brackets to have it evaluate to its value:

```
let name = 'NAME';

firebase.firestore.collection('test').doc('main').update({
  [name]: 'text'
})
```